# can not set sampling rate and encoding bit rate for MediaRecorder

Tags: android, audio-recording

I need to record the user voice in good quality many times. I can not use AudioRecord-AudioTrack approach, because I got huge size files and it is not appropriate for me. 3gp format + nb encoder give me poor quality of recording. So I decided to use mpeg4 format with aac encoder, but their default bit rate is 8.000kHz and I want to raise this value.
I tried to use methods setAudioSamplingRate and setAudioEncodingBitrate, but they did not affect on record quality. I put different values for these method (16, 20, 16000, 40000, 44100, 96000) without any result.
Maybe  this is device specific behavior - I use Samsung Galaxy Tab.
Does somebody know how to make the audio recording quality better?

Comment: You should be able to set sampling rate from 8kHz to 48kHz, see the table here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

Many devices only provide mono recording.